# TCP send data and get response return nothing

Tags: vb.net, tcp, stream, networkstream

I want get data response immediately after send data to server, this is my code, NetworkStream.DataAvailable always return false, I can not read data from NetworkStream:

```
Public Async Function SendAndGetReply(ByVal data() As Byte, Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 1000) As Task(Of Byte())
    Dim buffer(4095) As Byte
    Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
    Using writeCts = New CancellationTokenSource(timeout)
        Await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, writeCts.Token)
        Await stream.FlushAsync()
        Try
            Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                Do
                    Debug.Print(stream.DataAvailable.ToString)
                    bytesRead = Await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                Loop While bytesRead = 0
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
    Return buffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray
End Function
```

the full class:

```
Public Delegate Sub TcpClientsEventHandler(Of TEventArgs)(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TEventArgs)
Public Delegate Sub TcpClientsEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object)
Private client As TcpClient
Private listener As TcpListener
Private tasks As New List(Of Task)()
Public Event OnConnect As TcpClientsEventHandler
Public Event OnDisconnect As TcpClientsEventHandler
Public Event OnDataReceived As TcpClientsEventHandler(Of Byte())
Public BufferSize As Integer = 4096

Public ReadOnly Property RemoteEndPoint() As EndPoint
    Get
        If client Is Nothing Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Client is not connected")
        End If
        Return client.Client.RemoteEndPoint
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub New(ByVal client As TcpClient)
    Me.client = client
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal hostname As String, ByVal port As Integer)
    CheckServerUsedAsClient()
    CheckClientAlreadyConnected()
    client = New TcpClient()
    client.Connect(hostname, port)
    client.NoDelay = True
    CallOnConnect()
    StartReceiveFrom()
End Sub
Public Sub Connect(ByVal address As IPAddress, ByVal port As Integer)
    CheckServerUsedAsClient()
    CheckClientAlreadyConnected()
    client = New TcpClient()
    client.Connect(address, port)
    CallOnConnect()
    StartReceiveFrom()
End Sub
Public Sub Disconnect()
    CheckServerUsedAsClient()
    CallOnDisconnect()
    client.Close()
End Sub
Public Sub Start(ByVal port As Integer)
    Start(IPAddress.Any, port)
End Sub
Public Sub Start(ByVal address As IPAddress, ByVal port As Integer)
    CheckClientUsedAsServer()
    CheckServerAlreadyStarted()
    listener = New TcpListener(address, port)
    listener.Start()
    StartListen()
End Sub
Public Sub Close()
    CheckClientUsedAsServer()
    listener.Stop()
    Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait()
End Sub

Public Sub SendData(ByVal data() As Byte)
    CheckServerUsedAsClient()
    client.GetStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length)
End Sub

Private Sub CallOnDataReceived(ByVal data() As Byte)
    RaiseEvent OnDataReceived(Me, data)
End Sub
Private Sub CallOnConnect()
    RaiseEvent OnConnect(Me)
End Sub
Private Sub CallOnDisconnect()
    RaiseEvent OnDisconnect(Me)
End Sub

Private Sub CheckServerUsedAsClient()
    If listener IsNot Nothing Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot use a server connection as a client")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckClientUsedAsServer()
    If client IsNot Nothing Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Cannot use a client connection as a server")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckServerAlreadyStarted()
    If listener IsNot Nothing Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Server is already started")
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub CheckClientAlreadyConnected()
    If client IsNot Nothing Then
        Throw New InvalidOperationException("Client is already connected")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub StartListen()
    tasks.Add(ListenAsync())
End Sub
Private Async Function ListenAsync() As Task
    Do
        Dim client As TcpClient = Await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync()
        Dim connection As New TcpClients(client)
        StartReceiveFrom()
        RaiseEvent OnConnect(Me)
    Loop
End Function

Private Sub StartReceiveFrom()
    tasks.Add(ReceiveFromAsync())
End Sub
Private Async Function ReceiveFromAsync(Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 5000) As Task
    Try
        client.Client.ReceiveTimeout = timeout
        Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        Dim buffer(BufferSize - 1) As Byte
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream()
        Do While client.Client.Connected
            Dim bytesRead As Integer = Await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
            ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
            If Not stream.DataAvailable Then
                CallOnDataReceived(ms.ToArray())
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
                ms.SetLength(0)
            End If
        Loop
    Catch
    End Try

End Function
Public Async Function SendAndGetReply(ByVal data() As Byte, Optional ByVal timeout As Integer = 1000) As Task(Of Byte())
    Dim buffer(4095) As Byte
    Dim bytesRead As Integer = 0
    Dim stream As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
    Using writeCts = New CancellationTokenSource(timeout)
        Await stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length, writeCts.Token)
        Await stream.FlushAsync()
        Try
            Using memoryStream As New MemoryStream()
                Do
                    Debug.Print(stream.DataAvailable.ToString)
                    bytesRead = Await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
                    memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
                Loop While bytesRead = 0
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Print(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End Using
    Return buffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: You should start by isolating the issue.  There is a lot of code here and without a clue it is hard to determine issue.  First determine if the connection is completing.  Then find out where the code is stopping.  The issue may be either on the client or server.  It looks like you are not a novice from code posted.  If you were a novice I would be glad to help.  But an advance programmer should be able to give a better clue as to where the issue is actually occuring.

Comment: It likes NetworkStream to write and read are different streams, it suspended exception in Await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)

Comment: Then connection probably closed (or was never opened).  From cmd.exe >Netstat -a you can get the status of all the ports.  Check your port to see if it is still open after the exception.  One way of debugging is to open a file on client and server.  Then output debug messages into the file and include time in milliseconds.  Then look at log file(s) in client and server to see what happend.  Right now you do not know if client or server closed connection.  Another way is to use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler which will capture the data.  A close inthe sniffer is [FIN]

Comment: No, the client is connected normal, I can send data by  function SendData(ByVal data() As Byte), and can received data by function ReceiveFromAsync normal, but I can not use  SendAndGetReply to get response data under the same NetworkStream. (The server is third party agency).

Comment: The variables should global and configurated once when the Socket is opened.  You have variables declared inside methods.